# Calling a macro only once in the project

Tags: c++, linker, g++, easylogging++

I am trying to set up the `easylogging++` in a project, and I run into the following issue:

Macro `INITIALIZE_EASYLOGGINGPP` should be called only once in the project. Now, if I call this macro from my `main.cpp` and only include `easylogging++.h` in `main.cpp` - everything works fine. However, when I try to include `easylogging++.h` in more `.cpp` files, I get linker issues with undefined references (as if the macro hasn't been called).
If I place the call to this macro in a file that is alphabetically before the `main.cpp`, linker resolves everything normally. In the linking phase objects are sorted alphabetically.

Is there a nice way to solve this issue? Or will I have to try to force a different order of files at linking time?

I am not that much experienced with this sort of issues, tried googling it, couldn't find the solution. If there is already a similar question, sorry, couldn't find it.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Preprocessor macros and linker errors are seldom connected. Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us, as well as showing us the actual errors you get (copy-pasted as text, complete, in full, and without any modifications).

Comment: And a note on terminology, preprocessor macros are not "called" but rather *expanded*. In short, the macro invocation is *replaced* in the source by the expanded body of the macro, before the C++ parser reads the source.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, this is not a small project, so I'll try to take some time later to create a minimal example and copy the output here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some programmer dude was right, there isn't a problem with linking+macroes.

After trying to recreate the minimal example to post it here, I realized there was a bug in the CMakeLists.txt which caused the main.cpp (in which I expanded the easylogging++ macro) to be excluded from the build under some circumstances.

Thank you all for your time and sorry for the stupid question.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could wrap the call in a function that you invoke using [`std::call_once()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once), for example:

```
void setup_logging() {
  static std::once_flag once;
  std::call_once(once, [] () { INITIALIZE_EASYLOGGINGPP(); });
}
```

That way you can call `setup_logging()` multiple times, but the macro is invoked once.

Answer (score 0):

```
#ifndef INITIALIZE_EASYLOGGINGPP
#define INITIALIZE_EASYLOGGINGPP SomeLogic
#endif
```

`#ifndef` will check if the token has already been defined and in that case this section will be ignored.